# Can a variable be used in query since my parameter need to be elaborated before?

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm working on jasper reports. I've created a parameter called `Employment Type`, for which my code would fetch values from DB for populating dropdown values in the page.

The problem is, in db, table has columns Alias and table name, and alias value is "Employment Type" (space b/w strings). In jrxml, the query will fail if space are provided (i.e parameter value given as "Employment Type").

So can any suggest me how to fix it. Can I use a new `fx_variable`, assign the values of parameter to this variable and use in the query?

**The query**

```
SELECT Slno as "Sl. No.", EmpUID , EmployeeID as "Employee ID", EmployeeName as "Employee Name", cast(DateOfJoining as date) as "Date of joining", Department , Division , SalaryEarnedDaily as "Salary-Earned(Daily)", ApprovedOTHours As "O.T Hours", OTHours, OTAmount as "OT Amount", TotalAmount as "Total ( earned salary + OT)", employment_Type 
FROM Temp_EmpSalaryDaily 
WHERE ((EmployeeID = $P{EmployeeID}) or (EmployeeName like $P{Name})) and Division in ($P!{Divisions}) and Department in ($P!{Departments})and employment_Type in ($P!{Employment Type})
```

**Parameters:**

```
<parameter name="Name" class="java.lang.String"/> <parameter name="HR" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="Divisions" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="Departments" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="OTReportDate" class="java.util.Date"/>
<parameter name="Employment Type" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

Comment: Select Slno  as "Sl. No.",
  EmpUID ,
  EmployeeID as "Employee ID",
  EmployeeName as "Employee Name",
  cast(DateOfJoining as date) as "Date of joining",
  Department ,
  Division ,
  SalaryEarnedDaily as "Salary-Earned(Daily)",
  ApprovedOTHours As "O.T Hours",
  OTHours,
  OTAmount as "OT Amount",
  TotalAmount as "Total ( earned salary + OT)", employment_Type from Temp_EmpSalaryDaily where
((EmployeeID = $P{EmployeeID}) or (EmployeeName like $P{Name})) and
 Division in ($P!{Divisions}) and Department in ($P!{Departments})and employment_Type in ($P!{Employment Type})

Comment: Now if I replace  employment_Type in ($P!{Employment Type}) with                    employment_Type in Replace($P!{Employment Type},' ',''), then it would still throw an error

Comment: Ok now tell me the definition of Employment Type show jrxml definition.

Comment: these are my parameters,                                                                                         <parameter name="Name" class="java.lang.String"/>
 <parameter name="HR" class="java.lang.String"/>
 <parameter name="Divisions" class="java.lang.String"/>
 <parameter name="Departments" class="java.lang.String"/>
 <parameter name="OTReportDate" class="java.util.Date"/>
 <parameter name="Employment Type" class="java.lang.String"/>

Comment: the last one, <parameter name="Employment Type" class="java.lang.String"/>    may get multiple values.  Now because of space b/w Employment Type,  the query is failing

Comment: I imagine you have a string like this "'ET1','ET2','ET3' in it.. then you need to use the !, even if this is not the best way to do this (sql injection risk)

Comment: The correct way is to pass a List (Collection) and then use the $X{IN, command as in link above...

Comment: yes, I've put ($P!{Employment Type}), but if I remove space(i.e EmploymentType, instead of Employment Type), its not executing

Comment: I have tested I don't think it depends on space in your parameter, it probably depends on whats in it!!, its not in correct format...

Comment: If you need to change name you need to change both query and jrxml

Comment: my code fetches values from table based on parameters, & its column value is Employment Type(space exists).

Comment: yes this worked. that example in the link helped me. $X{IN,employment_Type,Employment Type}                                            Thanks a lot

Comment: Flagged as duplicate it would be useful for community if you acknowledge that.

Comment: Hi, I faced one more problem in exporting data to excel. If no records found then I want onlr the hearder(fields) to appear. But when report is generated it shows "data is corrupt, do you want to recover".

Comment: Since you showed good community behavior I will tell you the secret...

Comment: set whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" on the jasperReport tag (top tag) ; )